# Spring Views: containers/placeholders in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, spring, spring-mvc

I am writing a Spring MVC application, and have a specific question regarding the views. Since my model is not ready yet, because it requires communication with a service that is still under development, I would like to develop the View so that it is prepared for the actual data that will eventually come from the model.

I have the scheme, and I know exactly how it is supposed to look like, it is just that I would like to create a skeleton, with containers and placeholders for the actual data that will come in the future. I am new to front-end so I don't really know where to start, or what would be the best workflow to achieve this. What would be the HTML/CSS classes that should be used, and how to organize code to achieve that the View looks something like [image: this mockup]. So what I need are two main containers with visible borders. In the first one I will store only strings, and in the second one I will have 3 boxes in each row, and each of the boxes will store strings.

Any advice on how to start/what to use/similar examples will be very welcome.

Thanks

Comment: Well, usually you'd know the API from where the data is coming from. Therefore, you can write a dummy-implementation filling the model as required. If you don't have the model classes, use a map instead. It shouldn't make a difference to JSP or template engine.

Comment: @sjngm thats fine, but what I would like to know is how to write something like that in the picture... like what HTML to use for the container, and how to make the borders of it visible, is with CSS or what?